# compare two lists and return not matching items

Tags: python, list, compare

I have two lists:

`nodes = [[nodeID1, x1, y1, z1],[nodeID2, x2, y2, z2],...,[nodeIDn, xn, yn, zn]]`

and

```
subsetA_nodeID = [[nodeIDa], [nodeIDb], ....]]
```

I'd like to compare these two lists and return a new list with `nodeIDs, x, y, z` of `nodes`that do not match the `nodeIDs` of `subsetA_nodeID`.

I could do it like:

```
new_list = []
for line in nodes:
   for nodeID,x,y,z in line:
      for line2 in subsetA_nodeID:
         if line2[0] == nodeID:
         else:
            new_list.append([line])
```

This code is totally inefficient. I'm looking for a fast way to do this. I've tried dictionaries but I couldn't see a way to use them correctly. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to first flatten `subsetA_nodeID`.

```
ssa_flat = [x for sublist in subsetA_nodeID for x in sublist]
```

Or, if each sublist in in `subsetA_nodeID` is guaranteed to only contain one element:

```
ssa_flat = [x[0] for x in subsetA_nodeID]
```

If the nodes are hashable consider making `ssa_flat` a `set`.

```
ssa_flat = set(ssa_flat)
```

Then you can create your new list like this:

```
lst = [x[0] for x in nodes if x[0] not in ssa_flat]
```

Edit: If `lst` should contain the `[NodeID, x, y, z]` lists, simply change the first `x[0]` to `x` in the last list comprehension.

Comment: second the suggestion of a set ... that makes stuff a lot faster `O(1)` for set ... but `O(n)` for list +1 great answer

Comment: Thanks for your code. It works great but to work as I wish I changed `lst = [x[0] for x in nodes if x[0] not in ssa_flat]` to `lst = [x for x in nodes if x[0] not in ssa_flat]`

Comment: @jpcgandre Yes, this will save the `[NodeID, x, y, z]` lists - but you said you wanted a list of only `NodeID`s. :) I'll edit saving the lists into my answer.

Answer (score 2):

numpy is your friend for stuff like this ...

```
import itertools,numpy

a = numpy.array(nodes)
list_of_ids = itertools.chain(*subsetA_nodeID) # flatten
mask = ~numpy.in1d(a[:,1],list_of_ids) # intersection negated
print a[mask] # show the rows that match this condition
```

I also suggest making `list_of_ids` a set since set lookup are much faster (numpy may already do this under the hood ... not sure)

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a list comprehension to look through them all:

```
new_list = [node for node in nodes if node[0] not in subsetA_nodeID]
```

although I am not sure how efficient this is compared with other answers presented. As stated in another answer, you may need to flatten your `subsetA_nodeID` into a 1-D list for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Iteration though the entire thing is probably not a good idea for large problems, besides @JoranBeasley's suggestion, `pandas` is also an alternative:

```
In [52]:
import pandas as pd
nodes = [['nodeID1', 'x1', 'y1', 'z1'],['nodeID2', 'x2', 'y2', 'z2'],['nodeIDn', 'xn', 'yn', 'zn']]
subsetA_nodeID = [['nodeID1'], ['nodeID2']]
subsetA_nodeIDa = ['nodeID1', 'nodeID2'] #use itertools.chain to get this
In [53]:

df=pd.DataFrame(nodes)
print df
df.set_index(0, inplace=True)
print df
         0   1   2   3
0  nodeID1  x1  y1  z1
1  nodeID2  x2  y2  z2
2  nodeIDn  xn  yn  zn
          1   2   3
0                  
nodeID1  x1  y1  z1
nodeID2  x2  y2  z2
nodeIDn  xn  yn  zn
In [54]:

print df.ix[subsetA_nodeIDa]
          1   2   3
nodeID1  x1  y1  z1
nodeID2  x2  y2  z2
In [55]:

list(map(list, df.ix[subsetA_nodeIDa].values))
Out[55]:
[['x1', 'y1', 'z1'], ['x2', 'y2', 'z2']]
```